# Get Elements with AngularJS without referencing the document

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been developing an advanced web-based GUI in AngularJS. Recently, I decided to use the call `document.getElementsByClassName()` *(I hate using element collecting methods, but here I had to use one)* and my boss flipped his lid for accessing the `document` element. He says that I "need to use only Angular calls for everything", even for element collection! Is there an "Angular way" to collect elements by class name? If so, which way is better to use within the Angular framework? Please provide reasons why. Thanks!

**UPDATE: Why I need to use an element collector...**

So, I really wish I didn't have to do this, but I do...

I am using a third-party directive that I found online called the [Bootstrap DateTimePicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). Its pretty cool and very nice looking, yet it might have a bug...

First, I make a directive bound to an attribute, stating that the element I pass in is meant to be a "DateTimePicker". I then pass that element to the `DateTimePicker` function.

When invoked, this function creates a new div with absolute positioning and appends it to the body of the page.

Now, I open a dialog in my GUI that has a table in it. On each row of the table, I have two `DateTimePickers`: one for end-date and one for start-date.

My problem is that, once I leave my screen and the elements which the `DateTimePickers` were bound to are destroyed, the `DateTimePickers` still remain! If I open the dialog box again, it creates a ton more of these divs as well!

Until I could determine a true solution to this issue, I decided to use the element collector as a temporary quick-fix. I grab all of the elements with the `datetimepicker` class and perform a:

```
elem[i].parentNode.removeChild(elem[i]);
```

Comment: Are you allowed to load jQuery as well?

Comment: If you are doing this inside of a controller then I would agree with your boss. However, if you are writing directives and need access to directive DOM then that is a very valid use case (elem[0].querySelector for example)

Comment: @mccainz I am doing this inside of a controller. Can you explain to me why this is a bad idea? Also, what should I do instead?

Comment: Please read the Angular JS Developer's Guide, [Understanding Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller). Controllers should contain only business logic :)

Answer (score 2):

Not having your exact use case but knowing that you are attempting to aggregate elements by class name in your controller makes me agree with you boss. Think of the controller as an object which exposes data and and services to your declarative html page. The data is bound into the markup for presentation and possible modification. THe services are usually wrapped in functions on your controller which are then tied to event handling directives like ng-click or ng-change. These services should operate exclusively on your data and never touch the DOM. If you need to modify a DOM element in your declarative markup then that should be done through directives like ng-class etc.

In any case, It would be useful to know what you are trying to accomplish so as to give you a better idea of the "angular way" to approach the problem.

Comment: thanks mccainz, I could very easily place that functionality within a directive instead, yet I myself am very unhappy that I am using the element collector in the first place. I'll edit my question to explain why I am.

Comment: Just read your update. I think you have the basis for another SO question in order to tackle the problem directly. If you can recreate the issue in a plunker or fiddle that would be a great help. Update us if you decide to post a new question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks mccainz, I just might do that. Till then!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have my answer. This does not solve the question "Grab all elements with a certain class name without touching the document element" yet it does solve my problem and eliminates my need to use `document.getElementsByClassName`.

First of all, it turns out that every element using the DateTimePicker directive have an `element.datetimepicker("remove")` function.

I use a directive for each `DateTimePicker`:

```
components.directive('DateTimePicker', function() {
    // Requires bootstrap-datetimestamp.js 
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            dateTimeField: '='
        },
        template:
            '<div>' +
                '<input type="text" readonly data-date-format="yyyy-mm-ddThh:ii:ssZ" data-date-time required/>'+
            '</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel)
        {
            var input = element.find('input');

            input.
            datetimepicker(
            {
                //stuff
            })
            .on('changeDate', function(ev)
            {
                //more stuff
            });
    ...
```

*Directive drastically shortened for the sake of your eyeballs...*

I then need to remove the `DateTimePicker` and the `input` it is bound to from the DOM on destruction of the dialog box that the `input` is a child of. To do so, I added this to my directive:

```
scope.$on("$destroy",function handleDestroyEvent()
{
    input.datetimepicker("remove");
    input = null;
});
```

And it works! The `DateTimePicker` gets removed, the `DateTimePicker`'s handles to the `input` are cleaned up, and I've marked my `input` for the GC! WooHoo! Thanks everybody!

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for updating us when you solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you include jQuery in your project before AngularJS, Angular will use jQuery instead of jqLite for the `angular.element` function. This means you should be able to use jQuery's selectors for finding / referencing DOM elements.

Comment: Can't use JQuery either, and I agree with that one. I tend to avoid JQuery like the plague.

Comment: Well I'm no fan of jQuery either but it would accomplish what you want. Avoiding it when its appropriate to use it isn't very wise. I'd ask your boss *exactly* how he expects you to use just angular to query the collection, since he seems to think its the best idea.